# Can't get an http JSON response in the post http request

Tags: android, json, post, request, response

I'm try to receive http response in the folowing code:

```
public void httpRes (){
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String postURL = "http://validate.jsontest.com/";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "kris"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "xyz"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Got an error -

LogCat log:

```
09-12 21:48:58.099: INFO/RESPONSE(28485): {
        "error": "No JSON to validate. Please post JSON to validate via the json parameter.",
        "validate": false
        }
```

I've tried to receive response from GET requsets - everything was ok, but when i've tried POST request all variety of POST code - I can't get an answer! What is the problem? need help.

I've also tried:

```
Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
comment.put("password", "password");
comment.put("avatar", "httpssssssss");

String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
HttpResponse response = makeRequest("http://validate.jsontest.com/", json);
//Log.w(TAG, EntityUtils.toString(response));
try {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    String sss= convertStreamToString(is);
    Log.w("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS", sss);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.w("Exception exxx", ex);
}
public static HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

So, what is the problem?

Comment: I am a little confused here, you are not posting any json to that URl you are just encoding POST parameters, so of course it would tell you that there is no json to validate.

Comment: First part of code ok, I understand my mistake, but what about second?

Answer (score 1):

http://validate.jsontest.com rejects POST requests unless `Content-Type` header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

Via GET your line of code

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
```

should be

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri+"?json="+json);
```

and I don't think you need the three lines below that.

Via POST you need to pass the json parameter like so.

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json));
```

assuming json is a variable containing your json data.

You can test the GET method in a browser like so http://validate.jsontest.com/?json={validate: true}

Answer (score -1):

You need to post a valid json to the url http://validate.jsontest.com/ to validate it. What you're doing is basically sending a post request to the url, which is not in json format. 
You'll have to encode it to json and then send it to the validating url.